# How can i know if a relationship is fetched or not in neo4j?

Tags: lazy-loading, neo4j-ogm

For example I load an entity in the following way:

```java
Movie m = session.load(Movie.class, id, 0); // load properties but not relationships
m.getActors(); // empty since depth was 0
```

A bit later in another method:

```java
// Do I need to load it?
if (needsLoad(m) {
  m = session.load(Movie.class, m.getId(), 1);
}
for (Actor a : m.getActors()) {
  // ...
}
```

The only solution I've found is to load it every time.

Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

There is no API for accessing the session cache.
As a result it is not possible to get information about how deep the object graph got loaded.

I wonder how you get in the situation to need this.
The standard approach would be: load data from the database with the "right" depth, manipulate the data and save it back.
All within one transaction.